# What is my backbone version?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I couldn't find it on here or looking through google.  I might be doing my search wrong, but can anyone tell me how to find out the version of backbone I'm using.

I tried backbone --version, but that doesn't seem to work

I'm also using browserify, if that makes a difference

---

Thanks to Yang Li,

In gitbash the 'bower info backbone' worked perfectly.. thanks –  mc805

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your website, you should be able to type

```
Backbone.VERSION
```

in your console and it will tell you

Comment: It's giving me "Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined(anonymous function)"... I'm using browserify also, so that might be why it errors out... is there any way to do it in gitbash?

Comment: Are you able to use Backbone in your codes?  If so in your codes type the console.log(Backbone.VERSION);  this might be because backbone has been put into a closure by browserify.  If you installed it using bower, you can check the version through bash using 'bower info backbone'.

Comment: I still couldn't get it to show with Backbone.VERSION... but using gitbash the 'bower info backbone' worked perfectly.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow instructions on using Backbone + Browserify correctly there are some issues since Backbone doesn't load jQuery by default.

http://rkulla.blogspot.com/2014/04/using-browserify-with-jquery-backbonejs.html

http://learnjs.io/blog/2013/11/23/backbone-jquery-browserify/

You're probably getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError` because you're not requiring backbone properly.

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
console.log(Backbone.VERSION);
```

Also I hope you're using `npm` instead of `bower`.

Comment: I'm just curious, why npm instead of bower? @devkaoru

Comment: i believe `bower` is more geared towards `front-end` code where as `npm` is  more `node` base. `browserify` aims to bring `npm modules` to the front-end. Also you'd have to use something like: https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify for it to play nice with bower.